# Flat geometry, What is the value of BC Side?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, area

In a triangle ABC have AB =10cm and AC=12cm. The incentro(I) and the baricenter(B) are in the same parallel to BC. The BC side measurement is equal to:

I have developed so far:[image]

I did not calculate anymore because I do not understand baricenter and I encourage.

I already understand how Baricentro works and I encourage it, but what would their drawing look like in geogebra, according to this question?

Comment: This is REALLY not quite developed :D Barycentre is the alternative name for centroid, that is, the intersection of the medians

Comment: @BAI Maybe it means a barycentre of $A,$ $B$, $C$ and $I$.

Comment: Based on playing in GeoGebra, I suspect BC=11, if that theory would inspire anyone to discover a proof.

Comment: I already understand how Baricentro works and I encourage it, but what would their drawing look like in geogebra, according to this question?

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be a barycenter of $\{A,B,C\}$.

Thus, $MI||BC.$

Now, let $AD$ be an altitude of $\Delta ABC$, $AF$ be a median of $\Delta ABC$ and $MI\cap AD=\{E\}.$

Thus, $ED=r$, $$\frac{AE}{ED}=\frac{AM}{MF}=2$$

and in the standard notation we have $$\frac{h_a-r}{r}=2,$$ which gives $h_a=3r.$

Thus, for the area of the triangle we obtain:
$$\frac{(12+10+x)r}{2}=\frac{3rx}{2},$$ which gives $x=11.$

Comment: do you know how the drawing would look in geogebra?

Comment: @funfun   Obtuve  este resultado sin Geogebra

Comment: @funfun I don't know to use Geogebra.

Comment: Interesting.  I follow the second inset formula, but what is the first one?

Comment: @Matthew Daly I added something. See now.

Comment: Wow, now I'm going to have to go upvote your solution to something else because I can't upvote this twice.  Thanks for taking the time to explain!

Comment: @Matthew Daly You are welcome!